# Applying systemd control group resource limits automatically to specific user applications in a gnome-shell session

Tags: linux, systemd, gnome, cgroup

Having seen that [GNOME now launches apps under systemd scopes](https://blogs.gnome.org/benzea/2019/10/01/gnome-3-34-is-now-managed-using-systemd/) I've been looking at a way to get systemd to apply some cgroup resource and memory limits to my browser.

I want to apply a `MemoryMax` and `CPUShare` to all `app-gnome-firefox-*.scope` instances per `systemd.resource-control`.

But GNOME isn't launching firefox with the instantiated unit format `app-gnome-firefox-@.scope` so I don't know how to make a systemd unit file that will apply automatically to all `app-gnome-firefox-*.scope` instances.

I can manually apply the resource limits to an instance with `systemctl set-property --user app-gnome-firefox-92450.scope` (for example) once the unit starts, but that's a pain.

**Is there any way to inject properties for transient scopes with pattern matching for names?**

This isn't really `gnome-shell` specific; it applies just as well to a user terminal session that invokes a command with `systemd-run --user --scope`.

#### Details

Firefox is definitely launched under a systemd scope, and it gets its own cgroup:

```
$ systemctl --user status app-gnome-firefox-92450.scope
● app-gnome-firefox-92450.scope - Application launched by gnome-shell
     Loaded: loaded (/run/user/1000/systemd/transient/app-gnome-firefox-92450.scope; transient)
  Transient: yes
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-03-31 09:44:30 AWST; 32min ago
      Tasks: 567 (limit: 38071)
     Memory: 2.1G
        CPU: 5min 39.138s
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app-gnome-firefox-92450.scope
             ├─92450 /usr/lib64/firefox/firefox
             ....
  ....
```

Verified by

```
$ systemd-cgls --user-unit app-gnome-firefox-92450.scope
Unit app-gnome-firefox-92450.scope (/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app-gnome-firefox-92450.scope):
├─92450 /usr/lib64/firefox/firefox
...
```

and

```
$ ls -d /sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app-gnome-firefox-*
/sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app-gnome-firefox-92450.scope
```

I can apply a `MemoryMax` (cgroup v2 constraint `memory.max`) to an already-running instance with `systemctl set-property` and it takes effect:

```
$ systemctl set-property --user app-gnome-firefox-98883.scope MemoryMax=5G
$ systemctl show --user app-gnome-firefox-98883.scope |grep ^MemoryMax
MemoryMax=5368709120
$ cat /sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app-gnome-firefox-*/memory.max
5368709120
```

It definitely takes effect - setting a low `MemoryMax` like `100M` causes the firefox scope to OOM, as seen in `journalctl --user -u app-gnome-firefox-98883.scope`.

The trouble is that I can't work out how to apply `systemd.resource-control` rules automatically for *new instances* of the app automatically.

I've tried creating a `.config/systemd/user/app-gnome-firefox-@.scope` containing

```
[Scope]
MemoryMax = 5G
```

but it appears to have no effect.

`systemd-analyze verify` chokes on it rather unhelpfully:

```
$ systemd-analyze  verify --user .config/systemd/user/app-gnome-firefox-@.scope 
Failed to load unit file /home/craig/.config/systemd/user/app-gnome-firefox-@i.scope: Invalid argument
```

If I use `systemctl set-property --user app-gnome-firefox-92450.scope` on a running instance and `systemctl --user show app-gnome-firefox-92450.scope` I see the drop-in files at:

```
FragmentPath=/run/user/1000/systemd/transient/app-gnome-firefox-98883.scope
DropInPaths=/run/user/1000/systemd/transient/app-gnome-firefox-98883.scope.d/50-MemoryMax.conf
```

It has `Names` containing the pid, so that can't be matched easily:

```
Id=app-gnome-firefox-98883.scope
Names=app-gnome-firefox-98883.scope
```

and I'm kind of stumped. Advice would be greatly appreciated, hopefully not "gnome-shell is doing it wrong, patch it" advice.  Some [draft systemd docs](https://systemd.io/DESKTOP_ENVIRONMENTS/) suggest it's using one of the accepted patterns.

#### Workaround 1 - `systemd-run`

The only workaround I see so far is to launch the firefox instance with `systemd-run` myself:

```
systemd-run --user --scope -u firefox.scope -p 'MemoryMax=5G' -p 'CPUQuota=80%' /usr/lib64/firefox/firefox
```

and let that be the control process. But it looks like this isolates the firefox control channel in some manner that prevents `firefox` processes launched by other apps or the desktop session from then talking to the cgroup-scoped firefox, resulting in

> Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To use Firefox, you must first close the existing Firefox process, restart your device, or use a different profile.

**Edit:** firefox remoting when launched manually via `systemd-run` is fixed by setting `MOZ_DBUS_REMOTE` in the environment both for my user session and as a `-E MOZ_DBUS_REMOTE=1` option to `systemd-run`. It's probably because I'm using Wayland. A colleague reported that using XOrg and an older system it only worked for them *without* `MOZ_DBUS_REMOTE=1`.

#### Workaround 2 - as a user service

I landed up defining a systemd service for firefox instead.

```
$ systemctl --user edit --full --force firefox.service
```

```
[Unit]
Description=Run Firefox

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/lib64/firefox/firefox
Environment=MOZ_DBUS_REMOTE=1
MemoryMax = 5G
CPUQuota=400%

[Install]
WantedBy=gnome-session-initialized.target
```

```
systemctl --user  enable firefox.service
```

This starts firefox on login with the desired cgroups configured etc. New `firefox` commands will open tabs in the autostarted instance. I guess that'll do for now.

#### Better options?

Still a clumsy workaround - it should surely be possible to apply resource control rules to slices via `.config/systemd/user` ?

Comment: Related non-DE, simplified post at https://serverfault.com/q/1058898/102814 that focuses only on the systemd specific topic.