# Patterns or templates in systemd scopes?

Tags: systemd

I'm working with an external service that creates its own systemd scopes like `system.slice/someapp.slice/instance-400.scope` or `user.slice/user-1000.slice/app-1234.scope`.

The scope names embed the pid, so they are dynamic. The `Id` and `Name` both match the unit name exactly.

Does systemd offer any way to write a `.scope` unit file that will apply `[Scope]` properties to all instances of the scope by name pattern matching it, or is this something that can only really be done with the cooperation of the launching app?

Details/related at: [Applying systemd control group resource limits automatically to specific user applications in a gnome-shell session](https://serverfault.com/q/1058897/102814)

Answer (score 3):

**Drop-in files** seem to allow this kind of override. See `man systemd.unit` or [this documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html), cited below. I think the key functionally which will allow the drop-in to apply while ignoring the dynamic part (PID) is:

> Moreover for unit names containing dashes ("-"), the set of directories generated by repeatedly truncating the unit name after all dashes is searched too. Specifically, for a unit name foo-bar-baz.service not only the regular drop-in directory foo-bar-baz.service.d/ is searched but also both foo-bar-.service.d/ and foo-.service.d/. This is useful for defining common drop-ins for a set of related units, whose names begin with a common prefix.

I was able to create such an override for the user slice using the following (note the lack of PID after the last dash):

```shell
~$ systemctl --user edit --force app-.scope
```

Which open a file editor where you can add your extra options. For example:

```text
[Scope]
OptionOne=value
OptionTwo=value
```

You can confirm the presence of the drop-in using:

```shell
~$ systemctl --user status app-1234.scope
[...]
Drop-In: /home/foo/.config/systemd/user/app-.scope.d
             └─override.conf
[...]
```

For the system slice the approach is likely similar, except for the the `--user` flag passed to `systemctl`.